# In Node, how to run a function when specific text appears in stdout?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a child process to execute a `yarn` script and log it to `stdout` as follows:

```
const child = require('child_process').exec(`yarn run tf`)
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)

const functionToExecute = () => {...}

// When a certain text appears in stdout, run functionToExecute
```

This script launches a Terraform build that lasts several minutes. I know the build finishes when a certain specific text is printed to `stdout`. I want to execute a function when, and only when, this happens.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can try below.

```
const child = require('child_process').exec(`yarn run tf`);
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({input:child.stdout})

const functionToExecute = line => {
    //something you want to with ouput string(line)
}
rl.on('line', functionToExecute);
```

Comment: This is an elegant way to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From [2ality](https://2ality.com/2018/05/child-process-streams.html#reading-from-a-child-process) — a fine Node/Javascript resource. Something along the lines of:

```
const {chunksToLinesAsync, chomp} = require('@rauschma/stringio');
const {spawn} = require('child_process');

async function main() {
  const filePath = process.argv[2];
  console.log('INPUT: '+filePath);

  const source = spawn('cat', [filePath],
    {stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', process.stderr]}); // (A)

  await echoReadable(source.stdout); // (B)

  console.log('### DONE');
}
main();

async function echoReadable(readable) {
  for await (const line of chunksToLinesAsync(readable)) { // (C)
    const isComplete  = /process-is-complete/.test(line);

    if (isComplete) {
      spawnSomethingOnCompletion();
    }

    console.log('LINE: '+chomp(line))

  }
}
```